# What is the most 'professional' way to check if value send via form exist in database

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am a basic user of Symfony2 and doctrine. I'm thinking what is the best solution to check  if a value sent via form exist in database. For now my only solution is:

1. Receive form data in controller
2. Use doctrine, make query to check if value exist in database
3. Send appropriate  message to view depending on result of query

I suppose it is not the most professional way. Can somebody give me any guidelines? I heard something about own validator but I have never used it. Is it a good idea? Maybe a better way is to use doctrine inside Entity? Maybe in-build asserts can solve the problem? As I know rather not but I could omit something...

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Both Symfony and Doctrine have an excellent documentation. The better guideline for you is start to read it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Maybe in-build asserts can solve the problem?

A big Yes! ;-)

Take a look at [`UniqueEntity constraint`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html) . It will do the job for you.